# Do we need AMP page for website home page if any other page has AMP enabled?

Tags: seo, amp-html

We have a blog where each blog post has an AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) page. It is working fine and Google is able to show the AMP variation.
But in our server log, we are getting multiple requests coming in for AMP format for the home page of the website.

Whether do we need to have AMP format page for homepage if we have any AMP page in a site? My doubt is whether any crawler tries to fetch the AMP format page of homepage or anything else.

This is a Rails website and AMP variation can be get using `http://<XXX>?format=amp`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Google will automatically find out all the pages that are in amp format. You can create an account in Google Search Console if you haven't and then select **Accelerated Mobile Pages** under **Search Appearance**. Also you can submit sitemap.xml to Google which will be present under **Crawl** section.

Answer (score 0):

AMP format pages basically used by e-commerce websites. So that they can show the instant result on SERP(Search Engine Result Pages). Such as products prices, movie showtimes, availability of products. 
It is perfectly on you to choose AMP format homepage if you think you need it  for your website or not.